# How to sort and count on two columns using VBA in Excel 2007?

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet like this:

```
Item Category |  Customer Category
--------------|-------------------
     A        |         Z
     A        |         Z
     A        |         Y
     B        |         Y
     B        |         Z
     B        |         Z
etc..  on to > 35K rows.
```

I am trying to write a VBA module to count and merge rows which are the same in both columns, but keep coming up short.

I want output like:

```
Item Category |  Customer Category | Count
--------------|--------------------|------
     A        |         Z          |   2
     A        |         Y          |   1
     B        |         Y          |   1
     B        |         Z          |   2
```

And so on...

It sounds so simple, and I found numerous examples on here sorting and counting much more complicated spreadsheets, but can't get mine to work.

Comment: You can do this with a pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **easy** way using *Advance Filter*.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range, lrow As Long
    With Sheet1
        .Columns("E:G").ClearContents: .Range("G1") = "Count"
        Set rng = .Range("A1", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=.Range("E1"), Unique:=True
        lrow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("G2", "G" & lrow)
            .Formula = "=COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,B:B,F2)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I think this is ok with 35k. So everytime you run the code, it will summarize items in *Columns A and B* to Columns E to G. Just something to get you started. And of course the easiest would be a ***Pivot Table*** as commented by Tim. HTH